# Using .to_numpy() to copy specific columns from one row of Pandas Dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Dataframe like this:

```
     UniqueID  CST  WEIGHT  VOLUME  PRODUCTIVITY
0  413-20012    3     123      12          1113
1  413-45365    1     889      75          6748
2  413-21165    8     554      13          4536
3  413-24354    1     387      35          7649
4  413-34658    2     121      88          2468
5  413-36889    4     105      76          3336
6  413-23457    5     355      42          7894
7  413-30089    5     146      10          9112
8  413-41158    5     453      91          4545
9  413-51015    9     654      66          2232
```

And I have a dictionary of parent:child mappings for the UniqueID's:

```
parent_child_dict = {
    '413-51015': '413-41158',
    '413-21165': '413-23457',
    '413-45365': '413-41158',
    '413-20012': '413-23457'
}
```

What I need to do is loop through the Dataframe, and replace the WEIGHT, VOLUME, and PRODUCTIVITY values of the 'child' UniqueID row with the values from the 'parent' UniqueID row, where resulting Dataframe would look like this:

```
     UniqueID  CST  WEIGHT  VOLUME  PRODUCTIVITY
0  413-20012    3     355      42          7894
1  413-45365    1     453      91          4545
2  413-21165    8     355      42          7894
3  413-24354    1     387      35          7649
4  413-34658    2     121      88          2468
5  413-36889    4     105      76          3336
6  413-23457    5     355      42          7894
7  413-30089    5     146      10          9112
8  413-41158    5     453      91          4545
9  413-51015    9     453      91          4545
```

I've experimented with several possible solutions, and the trouble I'm having is limiting the copy in such a way that the UniqueID and the CST values of the 'child' row are preserved, but the other values are copied over.

The closest I've gotten is a loop through the dictionary where each pairing gets fed into this:

```
df.loc[df['UniqueID'] == '413-51015'] = df.loc[df['UniqueID'] == '413-41158'].to_numpy()
```

This seems to nicely replace all values from one row to another.

Any help on the exceptions or a better solution overall would be extremely helpful.  Thank you.

---

EDIT

I've looped the first solution into the columns that I want changed in the dataset like this:

```
columns = []
for col in df.columns:
    columns.append(col)
remove_perm = columns.remove('UniqueID')
remove_perm = columns.remove('CST')
print(columns)
```

OUTPUT

```
['WEIGHT', 'VOLUME', 'PRODUCTIVITY']
```

Then

```
for col in columns:
    s = df[['UniqueID', col]].set_index('UniqueID')
    df[col] = s.loc[df['UniqueID'].replace(parent_child_dict)].to_numpy()
```

This has resulted in the desired dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace` and `loc` access:

```
s = df[['UniqueID','PRODUCTIVITY']].set_index('UniqueID')

# using to_numpy here :-)
df['PRODUCTIVITY'] = s.loc[df['UniqueID'].replace(parent_child_dict)].to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
    UniqueID  CST  WEIGHT  VOLUME  PRODUCTIVITY
0  413-20012    3     123      12          7894
1  413-45365    1     889      75          4545
2  413-21165    8     554      13          7894
3  413-24354    1     387      35          7649
4  413-34658    2     121      88          2468
5  413-36889    4     105      76          3336
6  413-23457    5     355      42          7894
7  413-30089    5     146      10          9112
8  413-41158    5     453      91          4545
9  413-51015    9     654      66          4545
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional help, this seems to have successfully replaced the PRODUCTIVITY value in the child rows, but did not update the WEIGHT and VOLUME values.  What would be the most ideal way to replace all three while preserving UniqueID and CST?

Comment: I've fed your suggestion into a loop that does one column at a time (will show code in main post).  I would suspect there is a more efficient way to do this, but from what I can tell it is working on the real dataset and it runs quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

First create a mapping out of your `UniqueID` and `PRODUCTIVITY`.

Then use your parent child to map your ids:

```
mapping = df.set_index('UniqueID')['PRODUCTIVITY'].to_dict()
df['PRODUCTIVITY'] = (
    df['UniqueID'].map(parent_child_dict).map(mapping).fillna(df['PRODUCTIVITY']).astype(int)
)
print(df)
    UniqueID  CST  WEIGHT  VOLUME  PRODUCTIVITY
0  413-20012    3     123      12          7894
1  413-45365    1     889      75          4545
2  413-21165    8     554      13          7894
3  413-24354    1     387      35          7649
4  413-34658    2     121      88          2468
5  413-36889    4     105      76          3336
6  413-23457    5     355      42          7894
7  413-30089    5     146      10          9112
8  413-41158    5     453      91          4545
9  413-51015    9     654      66          4545
```

Comment: Seems to result in same behavior as other suggestion, which is to successfully replace PRODUCTIVITY, but it did not update WEIGHT and VOLUME.  Wondering if I've phrased the question incorrectly, but the goal is to freeze UniqueID and CST, and update WEIGHT, VOLUME, and PRODUCTIVITY in all 'child' rows with their 'parent' values.